# apt-get not working in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, apt-get

**ANSWER**: I still don't know what was really wrong but after I restarted docker and ran it again (same dockerfile, same everything), it worked fine.

I'm using Docker on Windows and my Dockerfile is

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04

COPY . /src

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs 
...etc
```

but when I try to build the image I get

```
WARN[0001] SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a Linux Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories

...

Step 3: RUN apt-get -y update
 --> Using cache
 --->ccd4120f98dd
Removing intermediate container 255796bdef29
Step 4: RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
 ---> Running in f6c1d5a54c7a
Reading package lists...
Reading dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package nodejs
INFO[0029] The command [/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y nodejs] returned a non-zero code:100
```

apt-get works but when I try to put other apt-get install lines in those don't work either so it doesn't seem to be a problem with.

Comment: FYI: you should never install your dependencies after copying over the source code. This will completely break docker's image cache any time you modify your code.

Comment: I note that the line in the output you cite is not the same as the line in the Dockerfile (no `-y`); are you sure you are building from the correct Dockerfile?

Comment: Yeah I am -- typoed the error message

Comment: I found that restarting docker.service and docker.socket worked for me. This if this command fails then docker itself is not able to access the internet: sudo docker run busybox nslookup google.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I restarted docker and tried again and now it works fine.

Answer (score 10):

*I had to put this as an answer since I can't format at all inside a comment*

There should be more output describing what went wrong. Try running these steps iteratively inside a temporary container:

```
docker run --rm -it ubuntu:15.04 bash -l
apt-get update
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Does that give you more information on what is breaking?

**UPDATE**

Try this and iterate on it:

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: Hm yeah those work fine but I still get the same errors when trying to build the image :/

Comment: If those work then there's something wrong with your Dockerfile syntax. Try creating a brand new Dockerfile and just add the 2 lines I added in the answer.

Comment: This might conflict with some SO requirements. But it helps! It's a generic answer and a help to people to help themselves.. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I separated the two lines:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Found the issue was with `apt-get udpate`.

Tried what Abulla suggested, apt-get update worked fine.

Deleted and retyped the `RUN apt-get update` line in my Dockerfile, and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I try your code

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04

COPY . /src

RUN apt-get update &&  
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
```

And for me everything works correctly

[image]

When I remove the -y flag I have the same problem

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04

COPY . /src

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nodejs
```

[image]

**Are you working with the correct Dockerfile?**

Comment: I am using the correct Dockerfile (I typoed the error-- my bad)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you use the correct Dockerfile. If yes try with an other image.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and `Ubuntu Xenial` and the problem was due to a `dnsmaq` server running on my host machine.

The solution was to disable this server by commenting the `dns=dnsmasq` line in */etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf* and perform a restart:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Hope this help!